# Как сделать такой интерфейс для загрузки файлов?

Tags: вёрстка

как сделать такой вид для загрузки файлов + методом dropdown как показано на картинке. Если плагинами, посоветуйте пожалуйста какой ни будь
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удобный плагин для реализации Drag and drop. [DropzoneJS](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) (пролистай вниз чтобы увидеть пример)...

Comment: Отличный плагин
Огромное спасибо